# OctoberCMS - What is the proper way to override or customize layouts, templates, and brandCss while keeping Backend -> Mail branding functional

Tags: octobercms

New to October CMS here...

I want to customize the layouts, templates, and the brandCss css rules that are used for Backend -> Mail branding. How can I do this and keep the Backend -> Mail branding customization of colors functional?

I know I can just edit layouts and templates in the backend, that is not exactly what I am asking about. Editing those will not let me change brandCss, and will not let me edit the layout used to preview brandCss changes in Backend -> Mail branding.

It looks like I can create new custom layouts and templates in module/system/views/mail, then register them in modules/system/ServiceProvider.php. And I can change the original brandCss colors in module/system/models/mailbrandsetting/custom.less.

Can I get a hint as to how to override these things in my own plugin rather than edit module/system files?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a new layout in the backend the CSS portion there overrides the branding settings. I couldn't find specific documentation on it but in my emails the css area did overwrite the branding area.

Unfortunately I am not sure how to tackle the mail branding preview issue of the backend. I hardly use any of the default branding css and when I need to preview an email I send a test one to myself.

[image]

Also another thing is that inline styling also works and overrides the branding.

[image]

Comment: The branding css still applies with new Layouts unless you mark the option "Disable automatic inline css". Good to know that the inline styles will override the auto css though.

Comment: I would recommend still using CSS code to override the branding instead of inline styles. If you write `h1 { color: red; }` in the CSS section it will override the default branding css `h1` style. Think of the default branding as the default look. You can edit the branding css defaults in the backend or choose to use the CSS code to override it. Yes the branding still applies because it is the default look but you don't have to use it. @NikkiAaron